# Репликация данных в MS Sql Server 2014 или MS Sync Framework? Что подходит больше под мою задачу?

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных, sql-server, репликация

Здравствуйте. Постараюсь описывать всё используя метафору издательства, прям как в [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms152567(v=sql.120).aspx) Microsoft, чтобы более-менее говорить с Вами на одном языке.

Я читаю информацию по всему этому делу и, похоже, читать ещё очень много... Возникает вопрос. Если на стороне [издателя](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms152567(v=sql.120).aspx#Anchor_0) (источник реплицируемых данных) таблицы создаются каждый день под новым именем, а то есть используется механизм Partitioned View, так как поток данных на запись огромный, и нужно хранить записи лишь за определённый период, а значит их удалять, то пришлось сделать разбиение на таблицы, ибо так можно очень быстро удалять сразу целые таблицы из БД не ставя на колени сервер. Это всё необходимо и от этого не уйти уже, уже всё написано.

Возникает вопрос:

1. Возможно ли настроить репликацию базы данных так, чтобы, к примеру, читая данные на [издателе](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms152567(v=sql.120).aspx#Anchor_0) из разных, суточных таблиц (TABLE_NAME1_YYYY_MM_DD) я на [подписчике](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms152567(v=sql.120).aspx#Anchor_2) сохранял эти данные в одну таблицу (TABLE_NAME1). То есть, возможно ли настроить систему так, чтобы она понимала, что вот нужно выбирать данные из таблицы TABLE_NAME1_2016_03_01 пока они там не кончатся, а далее уже из TABLE_NAME1_2016_03_02 и писать все эти данные в одну таблицу TABLE_NAME1?
2. В моём случае какая репликация больше подходит? Как я понимаю, репликация транзакций тут вообще не вариант. Ибо на издателе данные так же удаляются, а в архиве (подписчик) эти данные нужно хранить.
3. Ещё не дочитал, про [MS Sync Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb902854(v=sql.105).aspx) и поэтому спрошу, а не эту ли технологию мне нужно использовать? Так как есть подозрения, что так просто не настроить то, что я описал в вопросе 1.

Comment: да, конечно почитайте происпользование фильтров при синхронизации бд